# Run command on multiple Docker containers at once

Tags: docker

I am wanting to run a command on all of my containers at one. Is that possible?

For instance, I have a directory that I need to delete on all of my containers. I have over 20 containers running at once, so going to each one would be a pain (yes I know that in proper docker world, I should not be doing this, but I am still in development stage and just need to see the result)

Comment: don't think thats possible. but you could easily write a shell script to do that for each container.

Comment: As @aschmid00 already points out, you can write a shell script that (for example) executes for each container from `docker ps -q` a `docker exec` command. You mention removing directories... isn't it an option to use the same _volume_ for all your containers, so that you only have to remove the directory from your volume?

Comment: building off rick's comment, something like this might work
    docker exec $(docker ps -q)  rm /you_directory

Answer (score 0):

You can add volume in all containers using key -v 
or define in Dockerfile

```
docker run -d -P --name web -v /webapp training/webapp python app.py
```

If you remove directory /webapp in docker host you will remove training/webapp directory on each container.

But you need define that shared folder on each container.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/containers/dockervolumes/